# Variation on binomial experiment

Tags: binomial-distribution, beta-distribution

Consider drawing stones from an urn with replacement.

Suppose the urn contains a large number of stones, and each stone has a color, and the set of possible colors is large.

Suppose $N$ stones are drawn one at a time from the urn, and replaced each time.
Suppose $S$ of them have the same color, $C$.

Can I write a distribution telling what I know about the fraction $F$ of stones having color $C$ in the urn?

Clearly it depends on my prior knowledge.
Suppose I "know nothing" - i.e. all colors are equally likely.

I'm tempted to say $F \sim \beta(S+1, (N-S)+1)$ as if I knew in advance what color I were looking for, but I didn't.

Should I instead discount one of the $C$-colored samples and treat it as having given me prior knowledge, decreasing both $S$ and $N$ by $1$ ?

Comment: Are the $N$ stones drawn out all at once, as a group, or are they drawn one at a time and replaced each time?

Comment: @whuber: One at a time and replaced each time.

Comment: "Knowing nothing" is far different from assuming all possibe values of the proportion are equally likely. It is better to use the Jeffreys prior which is Beta(1/2,1/2).

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent: I was trying to assume all colors were in the urn in equal proportion, but I will look into what you recommend. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The binomial still applies here if you want to just forget about Bayesian priors.  I assume we know that C is one of the colors of the balls in the urn.  Then it doesn't matter that there could be forty other colors represented.  Define X as the random variable that is 1 if the ball is C and 0 for any other color.  Then since there is replacement and random draws each time the number of balls colored C is binomial with some unknown proportion p and S is still binomial with parameters N and p.  S/N is the maximum likelihood estimate for p and it is unbiased.

Comment: + Thanks, but here's what bothers me about that. Suppose $S=N=1$. Then $F\sim\beta(2,1)$ whose mode is 1 and mean is 2/3. That's counterintuitive because it could be that a large fraction of the stones might all have different colors, so I really just picked one of those colors at random.

Comment: An estimate based on a sample size of 1 is always going to be ridiculously bad.  For color C it estimates it either at zero or 1. When you have very little data and a bad estimate a sensible prior will make things better.  This does not bother me at all.

Comment: Yeah, this is a usage where I had hoped to fully understand the distribution of $F$ even as $N$ gets small. As it is I'm using $\beta$, and it works nicely, but I have this nagging feeling I'm making a mistake.

Comment: With one sample point the data is really no help at updating the prior.  After 5 or ten samples things will look better.  The beta is nice to work with since it is the conjugate prior of the binomial.

Comment: Right, with 5 or 10 I'm on solid ground. Even with S=2 out of N, it seems to give a good distribution for F. Anyway, thanks for giving it a shot.